# Dart create instance from list of types

Tags: list, class, dart, types

How can I create an instance of a class knowing the index of the required class in a list? I have:

```
final List<Type> classTypes = [ClassA, ClassB];
```

How can I use something like:

```
var inst = classTypes[0](); // ClassA instance`
```

Comment: You can't. What if the types don't have an unnamed constructor?  What if they require arguments?  `Type`s generally aren't usable for much.   You instead could have a `List` of callbacks (e.g. `[ClassA.new, ClassB.new, () => ClassC.namedConstructor(fixedArgument)]`).  Note that this would forgo static type-safety for the returned object, but you can't *statically* type-check that anyway since it's inherently a *dynamic* operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to use [mirrors](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.3/dart-mirrors/dart-mirrors-library.html) in order to do this. But keep in mind that mirrors is only supported when running on the dart vm, and will not work in flutter for example.

```dart
import 'dart:mirrors' as mirrors;

void main() {
  final List<Type> classTypes = [ClassA, ClassB];
  var inst = mirrors
      .reflectClass(classTypes[0])
      .newInstance(Symbol.empty, []).reflectee;
  print(inst);
}

class ClassA {}
class ClassB {}
```

An alternative that doesn't rely on mirrors would be to instead populate the list with constructor functions.

```dart
void main() {
  final List<dynamic Function()> classConstructors = [ClassA.new, ClassB.new];
  var inst = classConstructors[0]();
  print(inst);
}

class ClassA {}
class ClassB {}
```